# Insert values from maps into another map

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a for loop that generates a map with type of error (from a file.txt) and how many times it occurs. This is inside shown as a map. For example: {' Check failed for display ': 8, ...}. The for loop take each txt file and finds how many times each error happends. However, I want to insert the results from each file.txt into a map located outside the for loop so I can find the total number for "check failed for display, and not only get 8 from the firt time i runs and 3 the next time the for loop runs with a different txt file.

I have this code:

```
totalErrors={}

    for k in sorted(ErrorTypes):
        if (ErrorTypes[k] not in totalErrors):
            totalErrors += ErrorTypes[k]
```

ErrorTypes is the map generated inside the for loop for each txt file. And totalErrors is the map I want to compare every result. So for "check failes for display I want to get: totalErrors = {'check failed for display', 11 ...}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `k` as a key to the  new dictionary, instead of using `+` operator:

```
totalErrors={}

for k in sorted(ErrorTypes):
    if (ErrorTypes[k] not in totalErrors):
        totalErrors[k] = ErrorTypes[k]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I only get the latest value from the last time the for loop ran, and not the result from every iteration. Do you know why?

Comment: @olovia-solfjell Maybe the issue is in `if (ErrorTypes[k] not in totalErrors):`

Comment: Yes, that would be possible, because if k is not in totalErrors i would like to add the string and the value, but if it is, I would like to just like to add so that if it is already 3 times and the for loop now generates 5 times it wil be shown as 8.